# Can't disable Ansible's host key checking

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, vagrant, ansible

I'm using *Ansible 1.5.4* to provision my *Vagrant 1.4.3* box on *Ubuntu 14.04 LTS*.

I'm getting the following error message in verbose mode:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

I can do: `export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=False` and I have following lines in my `~/.ansible.cfg`:

```
[defaults]
host_key_checking = False
```

But it doesn't help.

What could be the problem? Thank you!

#### UPDATE #1

I'm calling it directly like this (without using `vagrant` command):

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml -i inventory.ini --user=vagrant --ask-pass -vvvv
```

The inventory is:

```
[default]
localhost:2222
```

Comment: can you ssh directly to the vagrant instance? what command do you use for that?

Comment: Yes @tedder42, I can do: `vagrant ssh` and it works fine. However, when I do: `ssh vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2222` I'm getting the same error.

Comment: okay @Slava next step: `ssh -o IdentityFile=~/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_key -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1`

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. Yes @tedder42, I were able to log into the vagrant box with the specified command.

Comment: @tedder42 will you be able to help me please? )

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to set it via the `Vagrantfile` of the project. When the Vagrant Ansible provisioner makes the call to `ansible-playbook` it *always* [sets the value of the `ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING` environment variable](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/v1.5.4/plugins/provisioners/ansible/provisioner.rb#L58).

Ansible itself [takes the value of the environment variable if present](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/release1.5.5/lib/ansible/constants.py#L48). Therefore Vagrant will override the value used in your `ansible.cfg`.

Therefore you just need something like:

```
machine.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
  ansible.host_key_checking = false
  # etc.
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've forgot to mention that I'm running this playbook using `ansible-playbook` command without invoking `Vagrant` itself. I've updated my question (see UPD#1). By the way I also have this line in the `Vagrantfile`.

Answer (score 7):

Probably not your problem, but worth a shot: I was stalled on this, until I realized I added

`host_key_checking = False`

under a session that was not `[defaults]`. Once I **actually** moved it to under `[defaults]`, changed host keys did not stop anything anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I can now do my ansible command without accepting the key fingerprint