# Ansible and the RSA validation prompt

Tags: ansible

I'm using Ansible to build my cloud infrastructure.  I don't mind verifying "yes" when I'm prompted to do so to verify the RSA key fingerprint.

However, this becomes counter productive if I'm trying to spin up and configure 50+ machines at a time.  Is there a way to disable to using Ansible...or to at least just answer it once?

Comment: You mean initial SSH connection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't disable Ansible's host key checking](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492032/cant-disable-ansibles-host-key-checking)

Comment: Also see this section in the Ansible docs: https://docs.ansible.com/intro_getting_started.html#host-key-checking

Answer (score 3):

As David mentioned you can use `ansible.cfg` to skip checking with `host_key_checking = False`, but if you're paranoid you might prefer using the [ansible sshknownhosts module](https://github.com/bfmartin/ansible-sshknownhosts) to accept the keys the first time, or whenever your keys change (eg. when destroying and rebuilding a staging environment).

Comment: You can also set the an environment variable, ie: export ANSIBLE_HOST_KEY_CHECKING=false